# project upgrade changes merging with customized version

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge, nopcommerce

I'm running an open source ecommerce store (nopcommerce) and have made a lot of customizations to the store.

Every time a new version of the software is released, I use winmerge to try to detect which files have changed, and then merge these changes into the project. This works OK but as my customization have grown, this task has become increasingly problematic.

What I'd really like to do is be able to get a diff from my current version to the new version, and then go through and apply the changes that I want. 
If I use TFS for this, is there a standard way to accomplish this?  Perhaps a 3-way merge app would do the job better?

To complicate things a bit further, I'm using the theming support to add my modified views in another location, so the changes from version to version need to be figured out and applied to the files in this additional folder as well.

In fact this is where the big headache comes in- determining which changed I made, and which ones are new changes from the new version.

Answer (score 1):

nopCommerce hosts its source code in [Mercurial via CodePlex](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).  All you really need to do is clone their repository and make changes to your local clone.  Then, you can either keep up with their modifications or wait until the next release comes out, then get an update from their repo and merge it with your changes.  Mercurial, being a distributed version control system, just does merges well, and you will have fewer problems if you try to do something manually for yourself using Subversion, TFS, or anything but Mercurial.  Go download [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), which gives you both a nice GUI and the command-line tools for Mercurial.  TortoiseHg comes with the KDiff3 merge tool, but I highly recommend [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).  It's not free, but I'd pay for this software a hundred times over.

As always, if you need help with using Mercurial, see the [Hg Book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I have used both TFS and [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and I strongly recommend Subversion (source repository) with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (command line) and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) (integrated into Visual Studio).

With these tools, it is very, very easy to find out exactly what files have changed and, more importantly, rollback to a previous version in the event that something goes horribly wrong.

You can also add [CruiseControl](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/) continuous integration to automatically build your solution and run unit tests on each checkin to ensure that you didn't inadvertently break something.